# Unable to run write-attribute in jboss EAP 6.3.3 CLI

Tags: java-8, jboss-eap-6

I am trying to run the below java code in my custom app:

I am using JBoss EAP 6.3.3 with Java 1.8.0_92 have also used Java 7. This used to work in JBoss EAP 6.3.2 (java 7)

```
ccp = new CLICommandParser(standalone + "/subsystem=security/security-domain=EncryptDBPassword/authentication=classic:write-attribute"
                + "(name=login-modules,value=["
                + "{flag=required,code=org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule,"
                + "module-options=[(username=" + dbUser + "),(password=" + dbPassword + "),(managedConnectionFactoryName=jboss.jca:name=jdbc/fooDS),(service=XATxCM)]}"
                + "])");
        ccp.execute(client, true);
```

The error I get is, the security domain gets security-domain gets added by fails in next line of code mentioned above.

```
INFONFO:  Command executed sucessfully: /subsystem=security/security-domain=EncryptDBPasswordXA/authentication=classic:add
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
       at org.jboss.dmr.ModelValue.addChild(ModelValue.java:120)
       at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.add(ModelNode.java:1116)
       at org.jboss.dmr.ModelNode.add(ModelNode.java:930)
       at com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser.getListArgs(App.java:1417)
       at com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser.getNameOrValue(App.java:1448)
       at com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser.getListArgs(App.java:1380)
       at com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser.getNameOrValue(App.java:1460)
       at com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser.getListArgs(App.java:1363)
       at com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser.getNameOrValue(App.java:1448)
       at com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser.getListArgs(App.java:1380)
       at com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser.setOPArgs(App.java:1344)
       at com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser.setCommand(App.java:1253)
       at com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser.<init>(App.java:1224)
       at com.foo.org.App.addSecurity(App.java:492)
       at com.foo.org.App.run(App.java:176)
       at com.foo.org.App.main(App.java:54)
```

I can however run the same command in JBoss CLI and this works. Is there a change I need to do around the code, seems like patch 3 doesn't like to use "write-attribute" in JBoss CLI.

Any pointers will be grateful.

Comment: It's tough to say without seeing the `com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser`. Likely the `ModelType` of the `ModelNode` in the `getListArgs()` is not the type you're expecting it to be.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins - I have specified ModelNode as: 

 private ModelNode getListArgs(ModelNode op, String args).

Not sure how you can attach the entire code. Researching on the below suggests the value maybe null but this is not the case.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/API_Documentation/files/javadoc/org/jboss/dmr/ModelNode.html#ModelNode(java.lang.String)

Comment: Yes it could be. You need to look at what's happening on line 1,417 of your `com.foo.org.App$CLICommandParser.getListArgs()`. It looks like it's adding something so you'd need to determine if that value is `null`.